# Overlapping body

Tags: margins, fancyhdr

I'm trying to keep body text inside its box but it overlaps the header. I tried using `\voffset`, `\headsep` and `\headheight`, but it seems they do not work as I expect

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{showframe,blindtext,fontawesome} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[a4paper, nomarginpar,margin=1in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{
    {
        \fontsize{40pt}{60pt}\selectfont
        Foo Bar\\
    }
    555\faPhone\\
    555\faPhone\\
    555\faPhone\\
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\linewidth}{0.4pt}}
}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look into the logfile of your code. There you find:

```
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
 Make it at least 80.59785pt.
```

That means you have to add an command to enlarge the `\headheight` to 81pt:

```
\setlength{\headheight}{81pt}
```

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext,fontawesome} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar,margin=1in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{
    {
        \fontsize{40pt}{60pt}\selectfont
        Foo Bar\\
    }
    555\faPhone\\
    555\faPhone\\
    555\faPhone\\
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\linewidth}{0.4pt}}
}
\setlength{\headheight}{81pt} % <=======================================

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your header is too tall and [`fancyhdr`](//ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) warns you about this:

```
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
 Make it at least 80.59785pt.
 We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
 This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.
```

The important part here is that you'll see the header fitting better from page two onward.

[image]

Below is a similar example with an oversized image requiring at least 63.60004pt; setting `headheight` to `65pt` is sufficient:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx,blindtext}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  margin = 1in, % Set all margins to 1in
  headheight = 65pt, % Update header height to accommodate for large content
  tmargin = \dimexpr1in+65pt % Update top margin to accommodate for large header content
}

\rhead{\includegraphics[height=5\baselineskip]{example-image}}% Something big
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\blindtext[50]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @Werner, your solution adjusts the header but body text seems to be misaligned, at least in my example.